# Condition which caused update failure in MongoDB (Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB(Mongoose ORM) and Nodejs. And I'm trying to update some details (updateObject) based on email and id.
However, sometimes it doesn't update because sometimes any one of the condition doesn't match.

> Is there any way to find out which key(condition - id or email) did
>   not match and caused update failure

```
let id = 'someId';
User.updateOne({ email:'rahul@xyz', id }, updateObject)
    .exec()
    .then((status: any) => {
        // Here I need to know which key doesn't so that it didn't update
        // If updated
        return status;
    });
```

In status object, I can see the update count to zero in case of failure but don't know if it can tell me the cause. Thanks

Comment: use this query inseated ```{id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}`

Comment: Didn't help, thanks btw @AfrazAhmad